# how to make access to a value in a Java Hashmap synchronized?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Let's say I have a Java Hashmap where the keys are strings or whatever, and the values are lists of other values, for example

```
Map<String,List<String>> myMap=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
//adding value to it would look like this
myMap.put("catKey", new ArrayList<String>(){{add("catValue1");}} );
```

If we have many threads adding and removing values from the lists (not changing the keys just the values of the Hashmap) is there a way to make the access to the lists only threadsafe? so that many threads can edit many values in the same time?

Comment: Yes, use a synchronized or concurrent list implementation instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a synchronized or concurrent list implementation instead of `ArrayList`, e.g.

- [`new Vector()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) (synchronized)
- [`Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) (synchronized wrapper)
- [`new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) (concurrent)
- [`new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) (concurrent, not a `List`)

The last is not a list, but is useful if you don't actually need access-by-index (i.e. random access), because it performs better than the others.

---

Note, since you likely need concurrent insertion of the initial empty list into the map for a new key, you should use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for the `Map` itself, instead of a plain [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

---

***Recommendation***

```
Map<String, Deque<String>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// Add new key/value pair
String key = "catKey";
String value = "catValue1";
myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>()).add(value);
```

The above code is fully thread-safe when adding a new key to the map, and fully thread-safe when adding a new value to a list. The code doesn't spend time obtaining synchronization locks, and don't suffer the degradation that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` has when the list grows large.

The only problem is that it uses a `Deque`, not a `List`, but the reality is that most uses of `List` could as easily be using a `Deque`, but is specifying a `List` out of habit, so this is likely an acceptable change.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class which implements [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) which can be used for thread-safe `Map` handling.  `compute`, `putIfAbsent`, `merge`, all thread-safely handle multiple things trying to affect the same value at once.

Comment: Question says *"many threads adding and removing values from the lists (not changing the keys just the values of the Hashmap)"*, so multi-threaded access to the map is not the main issue, multi-threaded access to the lists is. `compute` and `merge` are only solutions here if you intend to clone the list on every modification, in which cause you could just use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and get that logic for free.

Comment: @Andreas: I don't disagree.  But there are almost certainly going to multiple threads _retrieving_ the values from the `Map` (and initialising them, etc.).  At which point you're likely to be wanting a `ConcurrentMap` anyway.  I'd argue a combination of _both_ of the suggestions here are what are actually going to resolve the issue the OP has asked about.  (Agreeing your answer is significantly more thorough though.)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use the concurrent hash map which will synchronize that particular bucket.

Secondly atomic functions must be used, otherwise when one thread will use the get method another thread can call the put method. Like below

```
// wrong 
if(myMap.get("catKey") == null){
    myMap.put("catKey",new ArrayList<String>(){{add("catValue1");}});       
}

//correct
myMap.compute("catKey", (key, value) -> if(value==null){return new ArrayList<String>(){{add("catValue1");}}} return value;);
```